# image doesn't show up in appstore version of an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an image in an app that shows up fine when debugging on the device from Xcode or distributing ADHoc, but when downloading the app from the store, the image doesn't show for iPhone 3G.

I've tried extracting the IPA for the app and found that both the low-res and @2x version of the image are present.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What is the code being used to display the image? An iPhone 3G will be running iOS 4.2.1 at the latest; could be code that works on later versions of iOS but not 4.2.1.

Comment: I have a test iPhone 3G that's running iOS 4.2.1 and it shows the image when running from XCode. If it were a problem with the code then it shouldn't work when debugging from XCode.

Comment: That seems particularly weird. Does it only occur for this particular iPhone 3G, or any iPhone 3G that uses the app store version? A part of this is questioning which is the anomaly—that it is not working from the store, or that it _is_ working when built from Xcode. (Various caching issues for instance could lead to the latter.)

Comment: Someone else's iPhone 3G brought the issue to my attention so I had to go buy my own off of craigslist to confirm. I've tried deleting and cleaning the build. What other caching issues might cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. The image was being used as the background of a button. The issue wasn't a missing image. It was that the button was being positioned offscreen. It was being set as a subview of the tabbar of a TabBarViewController. I was using the height of the tabbar to calculate the center of the button. I replaced that with hard coded values to fix the problem.

Why was it only happening with iPhone 3G and only when distributing? I'm really not sure, but I was able to use the remote logging in the TestFlight SDK to figure out that the position of the button was off by >400 pixels.